# Tag score, difference between web and mobile?

Tags: discussion, bug, android-app

I use both the web portal, and the (Android) mobile app. If I look at my profile in both, I get a different counts for tags in both (screen capture of both taken right now below).

Notice that on the web, I have a 141 for the C++ tag, and on the mobile app, I have 229. It appears that on the mobile app, it's adding the answer score and the question score, whereas web display only the answer score (my question score for C++ is 88).

Why the discrepancy?

[image: Web Tag Score]  [image: Mobile Tag Score]